# Center a Navbar when using a fixed width

Tags: html, css, css-float, center, navbar

I'm trying to center the navbar while at the same time using a fixed width for larger screens. Basically I want to center the blue area over the grid, instead I cant get it off the left edge. At the same time I need the left and right side to be float left/right respectively.

[Photo Example](http://i68.photobucket.com/albums/i35/principe99/web_concept.png)

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-left">
    <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand icon-material-radio-button-on"></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-right">
    <a href="#work" class="navbar-arrow icon-material-arrow-forward"></a>
    <a href="#work" class="navbar-arrow icon-material-arrow-back"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
background-color: #f8f8f8;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1140px;
z-index: 1;
font-size: 14px;
min-height: 64px;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
float: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
float: left;
}

.navbar-arrow {
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can remove position:fixed, then you may try margin:0 Auto;
like here

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.navbar {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:0 Auto;
    min-height: 64px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
}

.navbar-arrow {
    float: right;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-left">
                <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand icon-material-radio-button-on"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <a href="#work" class="navbar-arrow icon-material-arrow-forward"></a>
                <a href="#work" class="navbar-arrow icon-material-arrow-back"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea, I need the navbar to be fixed at the top when scrolling down the page. That did work though, but the navbar scrolls with it.

Comment: you may also try:-
.navbar {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:0 Auto;
    min-height: 64px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:fixed;
}